# Why automatically redirected with Phoenix or jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, phoenix-framework

Versions
 Phoenix:1.3
 Elixir:1.6

I'm not sure if it is due to Phoenix or jQuery Mobile.
Problem is that after I insert data into database, it seems like automatically redirected next page. That is code only point I made, not all code, though.

```
def index(conn, %{"param" => param}) do
    render(conn, "index.html") #[1]
end

def create(conn, _params) do
    Obj.create_param(_params) #[2]
    conn
     |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :result))  #[3]
end

def result(conn, %{"param" => param}) do
    render(conn, "result.html") #[4]
end
```

[1] Display index page.

[2] Insert data to Database.

[3] Redirect result page.

[4] Show result page.

The problem is after [4], once show result.html, then soon redirect to index.html.
I wonder why? I have no idea of which of due to jQuery or Phoenix framework?

Are there any reason of redirect? I'm wondering Pipelines is due to it?
It should be stoped in result.html page.

```
[debug] Processing with MyWeb.PageController.result/2
  Parameters: %{"param_id" => "xxxxxx"}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 197ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was matter of jQuery Mobile. data-ajax caused to move page.

```
<%= form_for @conn, page_path(@conn, :create), [method: :post, id: "commitFrm"],  fn f -> %>
```

↓↓↓↓↓

```
<%= form_for @conn, page_path(@conn, :create), [method: :post, id: "commitFrm", "data-ajax": "false"],  fn f -> %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with that code except that `&result/2` is capturing `param` and throwing it away, which couldn't cause this.

Comment: I have no idea. I tried to figure out 'submit' or 'redirect' part in the pages. But  nothing seems to be wrong.